# How to run a tcl script from python file, and send other commands

Tags: python-3.x, modelsim

I have to write a python program which has to run a tcl script. This tcl script is a script which open modelsim. After I open modelsim (in the cmd, not the gui) I have to run the comman "run -all' (command of model sim).

I tried the following:

```
import os
os.popen("cd C:/raft/raftortwo/girobo2/ver/sim")
os.system("vsim -c -do top_tb_simulate.tcl")
```

I can see in the python console that the modelsin is running, and I am fetting to the point which I have to run the `run -all`

It's look like:

```
....
....
....
#   .windowmgr isa className
#     while executing
# "layout load NoDesign"
VSIM 2>     here I have to run the `run -all`
```

How can I execute it from the python program?

Comment: What prevents you from putting the "run -all" to the end of the do file?

Comment: @FritzDC - that's exactly what I have done:)